# Angularjs force resolve data before initializing controller functions

Tags: angularjs, scope, angular-ui-router, resolve

I have the following code in my application (stripped out otiose code so there might be typos)

Basically I need to be sure that `$scope.takeovers` has data before any other code is executed.

When monitoring network activity in the browser I can see that `/api/pagedata` is beeing called and successfully outputs the data I want in a `$scope`

However `$scope.takeovers` is undefined always.

Currently I have this wich is not working.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url : '/',
        resolve: {
            takeovers: function(pageSetup) {
                return pageSetup.getData().$promise;
            }
        },
        controller: 'newFormController',
        templateUrl: '/templates/form.html'
    })
});

app.controller('newFormController', ['$scope', 'takeovers', function($scope, takeovers) {

    $scope.takeovers = takeovers.data; //Is empty when controller is initiated...

    /* continue with code that rely on $scope.takeovers */


}]);

app.factory('pageSetup', ['$http', function($http) {
  var res = {
    getData: function() {
      var promise = $http({ 
        method: 'GET', 
        url: '/api/pagedata' 
      });
      promise.success(function(data, status, headers, conf) {
        return data;
      });
      return promise;
    }
  }
  return res;
}]);
```

**/api/pagedata** result

```
["2015-11-01","2015-11-02","2015-11-03","2015-11-08","2015-11-09","2015-11-10","2015-11-11","2015-11-15","2015-11-16","2015-11-29","2015-11-30"]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The resolve is making sure all data is resolved before instantiating the controller. Looking at your code my guess would be there is no field data in takeover as takeover itself is your data.  $scope.takeovers = takeovers; should suffice.

Comment: where does $promise comes from? there is not such property

Answer (score 4):

I think the final part of `return pageSetup.getData().$promise;` is your problem. getData already returns a promise so all you need to do is to return it directly.

```
return pageSetup.getData();
```

You can also actually resolve the promise directly in your resolve function and return the result of it. I don't think that actually changes anything in the simple case, but it lets you manipulate the result or grab a specific part of it before sending it to the controllers. So something along the lines of:

```
resolve: {
    takeovers: function(pageSetup) {
        pageSetup.getData().then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your input. I have tried that already but it doesn't work. When I console.log `takeovers` it outputs some kind of objec with alot of strange properties. Before expanding it it says `Object {defaults: Object, version: "10.0.2"}`

Comment: Even with the second version? I think a resolve is supposed to resolve promises on its own, but if you do it explicitly then I don't see how it could fail.

Comment: Unless your promise.success confuses it, that part of your code doesn't really do anything.